# How to transfer NSDate to offset time format in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, time, nsdate

How can I transfer a `NSDate` to offset time format (2015-08-05 16:33:29 +02:00) in iOS using objective C?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss ZZZ"];
    NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date ]);
```

Comment: BTW, if this date is to be used in database or to be exchanged with remote web service, he should also set locale to `en_US_POSIX` to avoid problems with users with non-Gregorian calendars. See [Technical Q&A 1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html).